# stochastic fluctuations

Tags: networking

What is meant by a stochastic process and stochastic fluctuations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathoverflow might be a better place for this question, but very simply a stochastic process is one who's evolution with (generally) time is describe by some underlying probability distribution(s). You can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process

Essentially you do not know what value a stochastic variable might have at some future point in time, only the probability of it having a certain value.

If the stochastic system has a [closed-form solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html), that is can be modelled by a continuous partial differential equation, then you can analytically solve for the probability distribution function. If not, then you can obtain the pdf by running a [Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).